# How to generate stepped distribution values based on min, max and likely values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math, probability

The probability density function is defined by three parameters: Minimum, Median, and Maximum [Codling et al].

[image]

I need to generate a distribution value (PDF) y = f(x) based on these values. I know this function: numpy.heaviside, but couldn't use it properly.

Example: 7.5 is min, 11.4 is likely and 21.7 is max value.

What I expect:

The distribution condition will be 0.5, based on rand samples from 0 to 1. values ranging from min to likely [<0.5] and from likely to max [>0.5]. Forinstance:

if the random sample is below 0.5 the value has to be in the rage of min to likely and if the sample is above 0.5 the value has to be from median to max.

```
if sample = 0.35, then value has to be from 7.5 to 11.4
```

for instance:

```
x = random.rand(size)

sample = []

for s in x:
    if s > 0.5:
        y = 2*(s-0.5)*(max-med)
        sample.append(y)
    else:
        y = 2*s*(med-min)
        sample.append(y)
```

But it never reaches to min value or max value.

*Codling et al., Probabilistic Well Time Estimation Using Operations Reporting Data*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sample from a step function in python/scipy/numpy etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777211/how-to-sample-from-a-step-function-in-python-scipy-numpy-etc)

Comment: no, it has only three parameters, not samples...

Comment: Look at the second answer: (1) choose randomly between first and second bin (2) sample uniformly from (minimum, median) if first bin was chosen, or from (median, maximum) if second bin was chosen.

Comment: I think you did not get the question, this is a PDF, probability function, what you suggest is different from what I expect. Or I misunderstood. Can you please add an answer?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how you intend to use the PDF you hope to get?

Comment: Sure, I will...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to define a piecewise constant function?

You could do this by combining several `np.heaviside` functions:

```
def pdf1(x, minimum, median, maximum):
    h = np.heaviside
    return (
        h(x - minimum, 0) * h(-(x - median),  0) / (median - minimum) / 2
      + h(x - median,  0) * h(-(x - maximum), 0) / (maximum - median) / 2
    )
```

You could also use `np.piecewise`:

```
def pdf2(x, minimum, median, maximum):
    return np.piecewise(
        x,
        [(minimum <= x) * (x < median), (median <= x) * (x < maximum)],
        [1 / (median - minimum) / 2, 1 / (maximum - median) / 2]
    )
```

Example:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20)
>>> minimum = -2
>>> median = -1
>>> maximum = 2
>>> pdf1(x, minimum, median, maximum)
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.5
 0.5        0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667
 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.         0.
 0.         0.        ]
>>> pdf2(x, minimum, median, maximum)
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.5        0.5
 0.5        0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667
 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.         0.
 0.         0.        ]
```